# URL for postgress DB on HEROKU

Tags: python

I am new to Python, and looking to deploy a simple application to HEROKU. I have added a postgress instance to HEROKU. I am trying to see the URL of the postgress database. Here is my code

```
import os
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL","NONE")
```

But i am always getting none, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to open a hosted [postgres](https://postgres.heroku.com/) database. You will get a URL after you create your account.

Also it seems like the syntax is:

```
return os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
```

Comment: I have created an account, added the postgress add on. my postgress is hosted at ec2-184-73-175-240.compute-1.amazonaws.com ? I can connect locally to the db but the above code does not work ?

Comment: There's a bunch of steps you have to do 
http://blog.y3xz.com/blog/2012/08/16/flask-and-postgresql-on-heroku/ maybe this will help.

Comment: just had to promote the url heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED_URL